# Can't find the JSON parsing error that the logcat is complaining about

Tags: android, mysql, json, parsing

I'm was trying a tutorial to get data to android from a MySQL database that you can find here:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

So this is the table from where I'm trying to fetch data:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pfc_db`.`capas` (
  `id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the fragment of the php script where the query is performed:

```
$query = "select * from CAPAS";

$sql=mysql_query($query);
if (!$sql) {
    die("The query ($query) could not be executed in the BD: " . mysql_error());
}
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $output[]=$row;
    if (isset($output)){
        echo "yes ";
            echo $output[0]['nombre'];
    }
    else{echo "no";}
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

It works perfectly on the browser.
This is the android code:

```
package com.example.androidconn;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidConnection extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
        // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.  
        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
        rootLayout.addView(txt);  
        setContentView(rootLayout);  

        // Set the text and call the connect function.  
        txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
        //call the method to run the data retreival
        txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 
    }

    public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.0.2.2/api/prueba.php"; //i use my real ip here

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

        InputStream is = null;

        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre","Escuelas"));

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getString("id")+
                                ", nombre: "+json_data.getString("nombre")
                        );
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }    
}
```

And finally this is the logcat:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(  313): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  313): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  313): --- registering native functions ---
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.androidconn/.AndroidConnection }
D/AndroidRuntime(  313): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  313): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  313): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
E/log_tag (  281): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value yes of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
I/ActivityManager(   58): Displayed activity com.example.androidconn/.AndroidConnection: 1636 ms (total 1636 ms)
```

I've been reading the comments on the tutorial so that maybe someone had the same error but I didn't find it, which is a bit weird.

I checked similar posts here, but they didn't help. If this question is repeated please point me to the answer, and if it's not, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like `result` is `"yes"` on this line: `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);` which (I shouldn't have to point out) is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `'echo "yes "` output is getting read before your `print(json_encode($output));` output, then the Android JSON parser sees this:

```
yes
```

where it is expecting JSON, hence the error:

> Value yes of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Drop the `echo` debugging statements from your PHP and leave your `while` loop as just this:

```
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $output[]=$row;
}
```

That should get you some valid JSON output at least.

Comment: Wow! I got no idea the echo's could affect the json output. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ferguior: Both [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) send their output to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

This happens because the data contained in result doesn't represent a JSON array. You should print the data in result to the log and see what is actually returned by the server.

Comment: That's interesting because now, after @mu_is_too_short answer, I get the data, but not well parsed.

So I've printed the result in the log: 
`try{
    Log.w('testing', result);
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`
But it doesn't print anything in the logcat. Why can be that happening?

Comment: Forgot about last comment, I had a spelling error.
The printed data I get is:
`[{"0":"cap001","id":"cap001","1":"Escuelas","nombre":"Escuelas"}]`
Isn't that a JSONArray? What is it then?